# Adding an error page for aad authentiactionn using react-adal

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

How do I redirect to an error page, something that says "Access denied", when authentication fails?

Right now when authentication fails it redirects to initial login page, instead I want it to go to an error page.

```
const DO_NOT_LOGIN = false;
runWithAdal(
  authContext,
  () => {
    ReactDOM.render(
      ...
    );
  },
  DO_NOT_LOGIN
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can’t control authentication failure, as if a user types bad password there is no redirect which is done by azure ad endpoints.
Also access denied is authorization error.

Comment: What happens if the user is not authorized to access?

Comment: Azure AD gives you the privelage to control access to applications.
When you add an application in Azure AD, there is one option which say users assigment required. The purpose of this option is to scope specific users to have access- this is called IDP authorization.
If you want to have App authorization, you can actually request a specific claim in the token and then build a logic in your application. 
In this case the access denied message can be customized by you. 
Check this, if you want to know how exactly app works in Azure AD - 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JKYycmcgT3s